# DateFormat parse from Json

Tags: flutter, dart

I added intl package and I trying to write out the screen

```
Text(DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format('${article.date}'),),
```

I am getting The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime' error

Comment: What is the data type of `article.date`?

Comment: `format()` is accepting a parameter of type `DateType` and you are passing a `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` method takes a `DateTime` and not a `String`

Assuming `article.date` is in an acceptable format for DateTime (Ignoring the data type).

Try this:

`Text(DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.parse('${article.date.toString()}')`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

For Current Time Zone

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy ').format(now);

Text(
          'Date : ' + formattedDate,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
```

If you Use JSON format  Date try below code

```
 String date = '';
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.tryParse(
         article.date);
         date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(dateTime);


 Text(date.toString(),),
```